# "Monitor: High disk read" while executing query against virtuoso local endpoint

Tags: virtuoso

I've a local Virtuoso endpoint and I'm querying it using Python (the query is quite complex). After a while the script execution get slower and start showing `Monitor: High disk read (1)`.

This is the Virtuoso log:

```
14:43:16 { Loading plugin 1: Type `plain', file `wikiv' in `/home/bilal/git/virtuoso/lib/virtuoso/hosting'
14:43:16   WikiV version 0.6 from OpenLink Software
14:43:16   Support functions for WikiV collaboration tool
14:43:16   SUCCESS plugin 1: loaded from /home/bilal/git/virtuoso/lib/virtuoso/hosting/wikiv.so }
14:43:16 { Loading plugin 2: Type `plain', file `mediawiki' in `/home/bilal/git/virtuoso/lib/virtuoso/hosting'
14:43:16   MediaWiki version 0.1 from OpenLink Software
14:43:16   Support functions for MediaWiki collaboration tool
14:43:16   SUCCESS plugin 2: loaded from /home/bilal/git/virtuoso/lib/virtuoso/hosting/mediawiki.so }
14:43:16 { Loading plugin 3: Type `plain', file `creolewiki' in `/home/bilal/git/virtuoso/lib/virtuoso/hosting'
14:43:16   CreoleWiki version 0.1 from OpenLink Software
14:43:16   Support functions for CreoleWiki collaboration tool
14:43:16   SUCCESS plugin 3: loaded from /home/bilal/git/virtuoso/lib/virtuoso/hosting/creolewiki.so }
14:43:16 OpenLink Virtuoso Universal Server
14:43:16 Version 07.20.3229-pthreads for Linux as of Sep  4 2018
14:43:16 uses parts of OpenSSL, PCRE, Html Tidy
14:43:16 Database version 3126
14:43:16 SQL Optimizer enabled (max 1000 layouts)
14:43:17 Compiler unit is timed at 0.000097 msec
14:43:19 Roll forward started
14:43:19     77 transactions, 6771 bytes replayed (100 %)
14:43:19 Roll forward complete
14:43:20 Checkpoint started
14:43:20 Checkpoint finished, log reused
14:43:22 HTTP/WebDAV server online at 8890
14:43:22 Server online at 1111 (pid 3556)
14:51:30 * Monitor: High disk read (1)
14:54:07 * Monitor: High disk read (1)
14:56:08 * Monitor: High disk read (1)
```

After a while I got a disk space warning because of a file named `virtuoso-temp.db` in `virtuoso/var/lib/virtuoso/db`.

I don't know exactly what's happening, I understood this is an resources issue but I think the database that I'm querying doesn't really need that much.

- The original turtle file's size is 4.5 Gb.
- RAM: 32 Gb
- CPU i5 7th Gen 3.40GHz × 4

Comment: This is quite Virtuoso-specific with enough moving parts that this would be better raised on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) or the [just-launched OpenLink Community](https://community.openlinksw.com/c/rdbms/rdf-rdbms-virtuoso). That said — "High disk read" suggests Virtuoso needs more RAM. Please confirm that you've [tuned the Virtuoso instance for the available RAM](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning). Please also tell us how much free disk you have, as those warnings may also be relevant.

Comment: The size of the original Turtle file is not terribly important, as Virtuoso employs a many compression techniques. The query being executed *may* be important, as that would be why the temp-db is expanding, and part of why the instance wants more RAM.

Comment: @TallTed, I've 100 Gb free. Even though I changed the default `NumberOfBuffers` and `MaxDirtyBuffers`, the RAM usage kept increasing along with the size of `virtuoso-temp` file, I think I have an issue in the query, I'll check it out.

Comment: The `Buffers` settings are primarily about the active working set; these do not set a hard upper limit on Virtuoso's memory use. [This page](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksAnalyzingSPARQLQuery) may help you (and would definitely help us, if you bring it to the spaces linked above) in analyzing your query.

Comment: @TallTed, in fact the problem was in the query, it had a lot of Optional(s) which made it complex for virtuoso to handle, I reduced the complexity by removing some of them in order for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution required more RAM and temporary disk storage than was available because

> the problem was in the query, it had a lot of `OPTIONAL`(s)